# Hard drive overheats when laptop running on AC power

Tags: 12.04, overheating

Here is the deal. When using 12.04 laptop runs so cool and quiet but immediately I plug in, the temperature of the Hard drive starts to go up. (hitting 60•C in no time). However when I unplug the AC cable, the temperature drops to normal levels (45-50•C). What could be done to correct this? Thanks in advance

HP PAVILION DV6700 
Intel Core Duo 2.0Ghz
4gb RAM
250 GB HDD

Here are pastebins of `hdparm` and `smartctl` on my ubuntu partition `sda3`:

[sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda3 (on battery)](http://pastebin.com/tSPSffhF)

[sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda3 (on AC)](http://pastebin.com/5pLV60iN)

[sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda3 (on battery)](http://pastebin.com/56W4DUQJ)

[sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda3 (on AC )](http://pastebin.com/k1DXeFmc)

[sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda3 (on battery)](http://pastebin.com/Nrfk5nT8)

[sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda3 (on AC)](http://pastebin.com/hKAsau67)

Comment: Make sure your vents and fans are not clogged and working.

Comment: Vents are not clogged and fans are working well. HD ONLY overheats on AC so it ain't a fan/vent issue

Comment: In an effort to save battery power your system is probably spinning down the disk when not in use for some period of time. When on AC it may be keeping it spun up for maximum performance -- generating higher temp. I believe but can't confirm that Linux has configuration parameters for this. The default power preferences in 12.04 don't offer control of this to the user. I've seen but can't recall the source, power managers with more detailed control. That is where I'd look for a solution.

Comment: If only I could change these parameters so the hard drive will behave exactly as it does on battery

Comment: In my experience, heat issues generally boil down to electrical issues. How old is this laptop?

Comment: Quite old :) about 5 years

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution:

`laptop-mode-tools` is controlling power management for your hard drive, and you need to configure it appropriately for your situation.

Open `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf` for editing with root privileges, and around line 276 (on Ubuntu 12.04), change this value to `600`

`NOLM_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=7200`

This is the amount of time before your drive is told to "spin down" or idle on AC power. 10 minutes with no read/write activity is reasonable.

And around lines 290-291 (on Ubuntu 12.04), change both these values to `1`:

`LM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254`

`NOLM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254`

These set the power management level granted to the drive, with 1 being "full" power management, and 254 being "almost zero" power management. The latter setting is the reason for your temperatures, because you can set the level, but *how* the drive manages power at a level is entirely up to it -- it completely depends on the implementation in the drive's firmware, and can vary by model, manufacturer, etc.

With the changes, we are now telling the drive to perform the same power management it does while on battery (which is satisfactory for you). This is different from simply allowing the drive to spindown while on AC (as in @EliahKagan's answer), because that would still leave the drive's power management set to near zero at level `254`.

#### How to determine power management level

To find out the current level, while on battery, AC, or any other situation:

`sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep Advanced` (replace `sda` appropriately)

Comment: Edited answer with further tests :)

Comment: No problem, depending on what works we can then make it persistent.

Comment: OK, is 47 deg on AC acceptable (since 45-50 is "normal" per your question), and was the performance acceptable?

Comment: That's expected because these only last until you switch the power source :) I'll post a persistent answer tonight. `-B 1` enables HDD power management while `-B 254` pretty much disables it.

Comment: @Mysterio: Please see step 1.9 in edited answer.

Comment: OK, next we'll force AC to the exact same settings as battery instead of meddling with -B.

Comment: See 1.99 in answer

Comment: (don't do 1.9 tweak - leave the old values as you did, btw)

Comment: darn, it's `laptop-mode` that's overriding the raw hdparm settings: if 1.99 doesn't work, edit `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf` and change `NOLM_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=7200` to `60`, 
`LM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254` to `1` and `NOLM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=254` also to `1`. Reboot and try -- THAT should do it.

Comment: BTW, thanks for teaching this old man a [new slang term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_homo) ;)

Comment: So 1.99+`laptop-mode` tweak is the answer? -- I'll clean up the answer and add explanations, etc. later today

Comment: It certainly seems to be the best shot at this problem and even though I'm not a hacker that tweak logically makes sense.
Also do have to set -B254 to -B1 in 1.9?

Comment: @Mysterio: final answer done. If `laptop-mode-tools` is enabled, that conf is all you should have to fix.

Comment: @Mysterio: accept+bounty please :)

Comment: how about the old tweaks we made in 1.99?
Enjoy my hard earned points ;)

Comment: Thanks, I hope to repay the favor someday :)   And `laptop-mode-tools` overrides everything -- that's why only the initial diagnostic with manual setting via the terminal worked.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried installing Jupiter?
(http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html)

set it continuously to 'power on demand' or 'power saving', maybe that spins down the HD

I have it on Precise Pangoling 12.04, works great (although i don't really have your overheating problem...)

Hope it helps

Comment: Jupiter & Powertop are both installed

Answer (score 2):

I would like to request you to test this on some other version of Ubuntu (like ubuntu 10.4 or 11.04 or 11.10 - you can use live version of those distro). If the problem still persists,

A. first check your earthing connection
because improper earthing always leads to the overheating problem

B. check your A/C adapter because it may be damaged and causing hdd over heat while plugging into the ac source.

c. Check your laptop battery a failing battery caused the problem with the adapter because it could be attempting to "overcharge" the battery, which doesn’t increase the battery’s charge, but, rather radiates the charge as heat energy (this is what is causing your overheating).

i will ask you to remove your laptop battery and  then plug it into ac source in-order to check the battery.

Comment: It took me 2 days to download 12.04 (crappy Internet access) but I will try it and report

Comment: BTW it's super horrible in 11.10 I had to stay away from Ubuntu as the laptop was literally too hot to handle

Comment: there are 3 possible reason which could be the result of your problem. i am adding them to my my answer, i hope this fix your problem.

Comment: @Mysterio which laptop are you using, add few details about your laptop if possible.

Comment: @ArkaprovoBhattacharjee: Sorry, but to be brutally honest this sort of Electronics 101 advice is nonsense considering OP's question. (a) Almost every laptop AC adapter is a switching converter which has nothing to do with ground/earth -- in fact, a lot of them do have 2-pin plugs with no connection for ground/earth! (b) No AC adapter damage is going to *only* affect the hard drive causing "over heat" -- the only possible damage is overvoltage at the output, and the laptop/motherboard's own power conditioning will  lead to either failing gracefully (shut down/refuse to start) (continued)

Comment: @ArkaprovoBhattacharjee: (continued)... or ungracefully (something will fail, leaving laptop unable to start) (c) This is also a useless suggestion based on the situation described -- he is monitoring his HD temps, not his battery or overall system temps. The HD temp monitor (internal) is NEVER going to be affected so much by external heat (like a battery overcharging or whatever) to report almost instantaneous 10 deg C swings in temperature.

Comment: @izx: i would like to inform you that i  already have faced earthing problem on my laptop that's why i have asked about it, and 2nd "a lot of them do have 2-pin plugs with no connection for ground/earth!" that does not mean every laptop got two pins  any way in the above question there's nowhere mentioned that he is only facing hdd overheating, he was just monitoring his hdd temps. apart from these instead of proving me wrong you should focus to help him isn't? anyway i was trying to help some one not to argue i hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

Charging your laptop battery generates heat.  So when you plug in your AC power, and your laptop battery isn't fully charged (it's previously been running off battery), it will start charging the battery, thus generating heat.

This is why you usually get the fan spinning up when switching to AC power after being on battery, and inevitably the system components will heat up due to the heat from the battery.

The hard drive, being reasonably close to the battery, will probably heat up a bit too.  This therefore is a plausible explanation of what you are observing.

There are other things that would cause your laptop to get warmer when it's on AC power, such as various components coming out of a "low power" mode, but the battery charging, IMHO, is a much more significant factor.

You say that your hard drive is "overheating" but only mention that it reaches 60 degrees.  In reality, [manufacturers usually list](http://www.scorptec.com.au/computer/27793-wd3200bekt) 60 degrees as the top of the "safe operating temperature" for 2.5 inch drives.  Your laptop manufacturer will have designed your laptop's cooling system so that the most extreme situation (charging battery while stressing CPU, etc) should still cause all components to remain within their safe operating temperature.  However, they make a number of assumptions.  They assume that your room temperature is a certain value, that you're using the laptop on a solid, flat surface, its ventilation holes aren't blocked, etc.  If it's 28 degrees inside and you have the laptop on your lap, then components will exceed their safe operating temperature.  Similarly, if the fan fails or is blocked, then it will also.

It's also not unusual for laptops simply to run too hot because they have poor thermal design from the start.

The hard drive manufacturer will have given some "breathing room" in specifying 60 degrees as the top safe operating temperature, which will partially make up for non-ideal cooling situations.  That is, if you go up to 65 it shouldn't be "too bad".  You probably don't need to worry about imminent death of your laptop.  But any heat will reduce the life of your components and the cooler the better.  You should look into whether the fan is operating correctly, whether you're using the laptop in a hotter environment than a typical room temperature, and whether you have the laptop on a soft or warm surface or one which will press against the air vents.  If using the laptop on your lap, get a solid tray/stand for it to sit on.  Some companies sell these with built-in cooling fans which I think is overkill.

Comment: What I'm looking for is to make the Hard Drive behave like it does on battery when using the AC.

Comment: Behave in what way? Your original question only mentions the heat issue which I've written about above. Do you want to clarify?

Comment: Meant how cool the temperature is on battery. I want that when running on AC

Comment: With all due respect, did you read my above answer at all?

Comment: Yes Sir I did and even up voted it. Please what makes you think I didn't?

Comment: Because I thought I explained the extra heat was coming from the battery while it was charging.  If you accept this to be true, why do you think you can change this with some setting?  You could, I guess, remove the battery - that would have the desired effect.

Comment: @neon_overload : Extra heat from ANY **external** source is not going to reflect in **instantaneous** 10 deg C swings in the **internal** HDD sensor. Unless there is voodoo going on ;)

Comment: How do you propose that this heat is generated then?  By a fault in the hard drive that somehow manifests when the laptop is on AC power?  I'm almost certain it'll simply just be heat from the battery charging.  It won't be instantaneous, but it'll be noticeable within minutes.

Comment: Short answer: APM/acoustic settings, upower/udev and possibly drive firmware.

Comment: see my answer for diagnostic info requested from the OP to determine which; surely you are not suggesting that the laptop charging circuit continues to charge (and thus heat) the battery even after it is 100% charged?

Comment: I feel the need to say software or firmware doesn't *cause* heat - even though it may turn on power saving measures that can cause hardware to heat up less.  You are correct in seeking more info from the O.P., suffice to say that I don't think this is what we're dealing with as power saving measures (apart from maybe turning the screen off) can't cause *that much* of a temperature reduction.  I'm not suggesting that the battery continues to charge once full (although faulty battery is indeed another possibility), just that when you switch from battery to AC it won't (usually) initially be full

Comment: @neon_overload Are you sure faulty firmware cannot make a drive run hotter than it would without any power-saving measures? Faulty firmware could make a drive access data inefficiently (reading and writing more than necessary to fetch or record the same data), move the read/write head(s) in and out more than necessary, and so forth. *Furthermore, you've suggested that the extra heat is coming from the battery as it charges...but isn't it more likely that it's coming from the CPU (and possibly GPU), clocking higher when the laptop is plugged in, due to power-saving?*

Comment: @Eliah Kagan no, not by 10 degrees and not noticeable immediately after switching to AC.  Notebook hard drives just don't use that much energy (less than 0.9W when spinning and idle).  If it was the drive, it'd be a serious hardware fault of the "runaway electrical current" kind.  But the battery *can* generate that much heat (and more) in normal operation - particularly during charging while the laptop is being used.

Comment: @neon_overload: Sorry, this is getting ridiculous. It's trivial to find a laptop CPU that will jump 10 degrees within seconds if connected to AC at close to 100% load. You do understand that the drive sensor is NOT measuring waste heat (the *P=I^2*R*) kind -- that heat is generated mostly from mechanical sources like friction - total power *consumption* has nothing to do with it. Finally, unless you are on an underpowered AC adapter, while the battery is being charged and after, the laptop runs completely off of AC.

Comment: Even while the laptop runs completely off of AC, the battery charging will still heat up the battery.  That is why it is my best guess for what is happening in this situation.  Heat generated by charging a battery is not something I made up.  I do not mean to claim that it isn't the CPU or another component, just that I really believe it cannot be the drive, unless there is something electrically wrong with it, and in my opinion the best guess is the battery, since that would fit well with the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

To enable hard drive spindown even when running on AC power, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and run this command:

```
gconf-editor /apps/gnome-power-manager/disks
```

This will open the Configuration Editor and bring you directly to the options for automatically spinning down disks. Make sure `spindown_enable_ac` is checked as well as `spindown_enable_battery`.

Comment: Are there any potential negative effects with this tweak?

Comment: @Mysterio I'm not aware of any negative effects of spinning down when running from AC power, that would not also apply to spinning down when running from battery. As for spindown generally, theoretically spinning your hard drives down (an back up again) frequently could shorten their life by putting more wear on the motor...if they spin up and down **a lot**. (Otherwise, it should make them last longer, because the motor is not running as much.) The only real caveat I can think to add to this tweak is that I am not 100% certain it'll *work*, as there may be other factors preventing spindown.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's half past midnight over here so I'll try it out and report in the morning. Hope it works :)

Comment: I would be cautious about this given [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdparm/+bug/952556). Lower-level APM/acoustic tweaking (see my answer) *may* achieve similar results without setting AC spindown to the same value as battery spindown.

Comment: @EliahKagan: please see [comment 74](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdparm/+bug/952556/comments/74), and others. The bottom line is that even with the patch this is very implementation dependent and when we have a desired baseline that the OP is happy with (battery settings), why not explicitly set AC settings to the same values instead of the nebulous gnome spindown (I confess I do not know what actual settings that alters -- can you expand in the answer?)

Comment: @izx Thanks for clarifying. I don't know the details of how GNOME Power Manager manages hard disk spindown. If I find out I'll expand the answer, and if anybody else finds out they should feel free to do so as well.

Comment: @EliahKagan : I'm trying to take the low-level approach to your high-level, trying to explicitly set `hdparm` settings triggered on AC to those that are triggered on battery, or similar, to come up with a temp/performance balance the OP finds acceptable :-)

Comment: @EliahKagan quite strange but *gnome-power-manager* does not exist on my system. Maybe this option has been removed in 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue on 4 occasions, since having several laptops since 2007. It didn't matter what brand(Toshiba, HP, Dell, ASUS)

Everything you're talking about is plausible.

My situation was resolved in the following way. As much as I have taken on board ALL the comments that OTHER people have also suggested, realistically all the 4 occasions were resolved after finding the one factor in all of them. When I replaced a NEW battery, the overheating issue wasn't a factor anymore. When I returned the OLD battery, YES I had what everybody complained about. In all 3 occasions I did the following; while assuming the battery was OK because I had often kept the AC connection plugged in, of course seeing the FULL BATTERY image made me feel the BATTERY was fine. It was easy to just go on with whatever I was doing. When I came across the issue with the hard drive overheating, I just happened to have a friend that owns a computer store that gave me a NEW or currently working battery(he tested for as reliable), then plugged that into my laptop. For THAT TEMPORARILY REPLACED battery, the hard drive OVERHEATING issue was pretty much non existent. Curiously, I replaced MY OLD battery that I ASSUMED was fine(because I LOVED to see it FULLY CHARGED), then I pulled out the AC adaptor to allow the laptop to run off the battery. NOW THIS is something that I OBSERVED in ALL 3 occasions, that allowed me to now SHARE this observation with you. In ALL 3 occasions, the battery RAN DOWN within the first 20 minutes(none of them went longer than 20minutes(ie 4minutes, 12minutes, 15min, 20min)) and the battery alert came up 7minutes remaining your battery is low. Basically the none of the batteries lasted as they would usually run for at least 2 hours.

YES I also cleaned out the fan and blew out the motherboard of any dust. My friend has the laptop repair shop. Even keeping the OLD battery, the same issue would arise, the Hard Drive would overheat, while I had the AC connector plugged in, AND if I took out the AC connector, the battery did not last very long(in my case under 20minutes).

Therefore, the issue was the battery that could not hold it's charge anymore. I had been keeping the battery plugged into the AC for about 3 years ongoing, & yes I also occasionally ran it on it's own without the AC while sitting on the bus or in the airport. BUT I MOSTLY kept it connected on the AC, like ALOT of people, FEELING the ASSUMED comfort that I was always 100% full power when something went wrong(blackout poweroutage in asia Vietnam, Thailand, Cambodia). In the past I INITIALLY did what everyone else seem's to always bring up, clean the fan area, blow off the dust, check power settings, blame the hard drive. After REPLACING the battery, obviously because in all 3 occasions it could not CONTINUE past 20 minutes without the warning LOW BATTERY POWER. In my situation, which SOUNDS like what everyone is talking about, the battery was the issue.

Is the hard drive LESS HOT when only on the BATTERY(not connected to the AC adaptor), YES in my case it was LESS HOT, whether it was on the NEW BATTERY, or even on the FAULTY BATTERY(that did not last longer than 20 minutes with the warning LOW BATTERY POWER).

But in ALL occasions, when the FAULTY BATTERY(assumed to be working well with FULL POWER STORED) was connected to the AC connector, the Hard Drive and generally underneath the LAPTOP area was OBVIOUSLY very HOT, then often would cause an automatic shutdown after some time(within 3 hours sometimes or after many hours under 48 hours). It didn't matter whether I had the AIRCON in the hotel room or a fan blowing directly on the laptop. The Faulty battery always appeared to have the issue with the UNDERNEATH feeling GENERALLY UNCOMFORTABLY HOT(hard drive area, cpu, memory chips).

Replace the battery after seeing it not last very long like I did, then YES for the next 2-3years we MAY NOT have the same issues again(Max 4years). BUT I now know the symptoms of this after 4 occasions. I don't waste time, after watching the battery not last long on it's own. I just get a new battery.

Will there be times that your AC ADAPTOR is at fault? YES, but in that case, your battery won't be charged fully, and you will see that it doesn't appear to be CHARGING the battery or show connected to the AC power. Replace that too in that case. Only cost $6-$8 in Asia, and lasted LONGER than the batteries. THose occasions I didn't have overheating. I just didn't see the battery being charged.

Hope this HELPS EVERYONE.