# How to configure power managment with tlp?

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, overheating, tlp

I have a similar issue like [this user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141343/hard-drive-overheats-when-laptop-running-on-ac-power), that is my hard drive overheats.

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 15.10, which has `tlp`, and I've read that they should not be installed together.

So is there a way to configure the things in the linked post with `tlp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install TLP and laptop-mode-tools at the same time (the tlp package conflicts with the laptop-mode-tools package to prevent parallel install).

I understand you want to have the equivalent of

```
NOLM_HD_IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=7200 # 2 hours
LM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=1
NOLM_AC_HD_POWERMGMT=1
```

This translates to

```
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="1"
DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_AC="244"
```

in the TLP configuration.

But i recommend against APM = 1. This could mean excessive wear caused by frequent start/stop cycles of the spindle motor and/or load cycles for the heads.

My recommendation for TLP is to try APM = 128 on AC (same as on battery):

```
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="128"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128"
```

and not to change DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_AC because a spindown timeout of 2h doesn't make sense.

Then install the package **smartmontools** and monitor the HDD temp with

```
sudo tlp-stat -d
```

Output shows:

```
...
SMART info:
  ...
  190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel   =       28 [°C]
```

Refer to the [TLP configuration docs](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#disks) for more info.

Comment: I should change that in `/etc/default/tlp` right? I've already installed `smartmontools`, and check the HD temp. from time to time. It's always above 40 degrees Celsius, is that too hot?

Comment: I have this in my `etc/default/tlp`, but I only have one disk ... sholud I change both? 

`DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"`


`DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"`